# The TextField does not save the text when returning to the home screen

Tags: flutter, dart

The TextField does not save the text when returning to the home screen, but when the **ElevatedButton** is pressed, it does. I added it for testing because I ran out of ideas. It is very difficult for a beginner to understand what the problem is, thanks in advance for the help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BookRead extends StatefulWidget {
  String nameScreen;
  BookRead(this.nameScreen);

  @override
  State<BookRead> createState() => _BookReadState();}

class _BookReadState extends State<BookRead> {
  final controllerT = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text(widget.nameScreen),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: controllerT,
              maxLines: null,
              expands: true,),),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen()));}, child: Text('test'))],),);
  }}
class AddTaskScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [Expanded(child: Container())],),);
  }}
```

Comment: read the following page carefully

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to clarify again how this works with navigation.

Imagine you have 3 pages in your app. Page A, B and C.

You start the app with page A. Page A is placed on a stack. Now you navigate to page B. Page B is placed on the stack, so A and B are stacked on the stack. Now you make your changes on page B in the text field and navigate to page C. Now page A, B and C are on the stack. If you now go back from page C, it will be deleted from the stack with all its changes and you will end up on page B again. Since page B is still on the stack, you see the changes in the text field. If you now navigate back to page A, then page B deletes itself with its changes, so when you navigate back to page B, you will no longer see your changes because the state has deleted itself.

Answer (score 0):

The answers directed me to the correct answer, reading the docs and correct controller implementation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class BookRead extends StatefulWidget {
 String nameScreen;
 BookRead(this.nameScreen);  

@override
State<BookRead> createState() => _BookReadState();}

class _BookReadState extends State<BookRead> {

late TextEditingController controllerT;  
static String texts = '';                 

@override
 void initState() {
  controllerT = TextEditingController();
  controllerT.text = texts;  
 super.initState();}

@override            
 void dispose() {
  controllerT.dispose();
 super.dispose();}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Center(
      child: Text(widget.nameScreen),),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          controller: controllerT,
          maxLines: null,
          expands: true,
          onChanged: (value){           
            texts = value;},),),
```